# How can I see if the string is numeric?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have the string `"08"` and I like to know if this string is numeric. How can I do it in Rails 3.1?

Comment: If you have string then it's a String. What do you need to know? If the string contains just digits?

Comment: Since you're using Rails, I think *when* and *where* you're trying to do this is important. In other words: is this because you're storing the value in the database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way to do this is to leave it up to ruby to determine it:

```
begin
    Float(string)
    # String is numeric
rescue ArgumentError, TypeError
    # String is not numeric
end
```

Comment: +1 for creative laziness. And for catching `+3` and `10e6` along the way.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a regular expression:

```
str = "08"
if str =~ /^-?(\d+(\.\d+)?|\.\d+)$/
  # string is numeric
else
  # string is not
end
```

Comment: That seems overly complicated. Why not just go with: str =~ /^(\d+)$/

Comment: @Forrest Because it could be a decimal number, in which case your regex won't match.

Comment: @Forrest: `/^\d+$` won't match negative values either. OTOH, `/^-?(\d+(\.\d+)?|\.\d+)$/` misses exponential notation and `+3`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to validate user input it would be just as simple to only allow them to input numbers with something like `validates_format_of :string, :with => /[0-9]/`.