# Regular expression to match number formats

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to write a small program that asks a user to input a number and the program will determine if it's a valid number. The user can enter any kind of number (integer, float, scientific notation, etc.).

My question is what regular expression should be used to keep something like "7w" from being matched as a valid number? Also I would like the number 0 to exit the loop and end the program, but as it's written now 0 is matching valid like any other number. Any insight please?

```
x = 1

while x != 0
  puts "Enter a string"
  num = gets

  if num.match(/\d+/)
    puts "Valid"
  else
    puts "invalid"
  end

  if num == 0
    puts "End of program"
    x = num
  end   
end
```

Comment: What is the format you like to accept? Without that notion, there is no way to implement it. Do you want to exit if the string is exactly `"0\n"`, or `"  \t\t 0 \t  \n"`, `"0.0\n"`, etc. as well? If the latter, there would be no way to input the value `0`.

Comment: What about currency symbols?  What else is in the "etc" range?

Comment: The answer by @thebugfinder should be taken as the best answer.  Despite not being a `regex`, if the OP asked for a regex solution only because they wanted *a tool to accomplish the job* then this ruby-idiomatic solution is the best. (and will probably see the most optimization as the language develops)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with, you are overcomplicating the loop, secondly, your regular expression needs to be a bit more explicit.  Try something like this:

```
x = 1

while x != 0
  puts "Enter a string"
  num = gets.chomp
  if num == "0"
    puts "exiting with 0"
    exit 0
  elsif num.match(/^[0-9](\.[0-9])?$+/)
    puts "Valid"
  else
    puts "invalid"
  end
end
```

This expression will match any number that contains a digit or a decimal, and will fail to match anything containing letters.  If the string entered is exactly 0, the script will exit with status 0.

Comment: thanks!so now im trying to include negative numbers. is this the correct expression (^-[0-9])

Comment: close, you want /^-?[0-9] so that the '-' is optional, the way you have it will work, but it would make it not work for positive numbers

Comment: ok so the prob im running into now is that it wont match anything thats two digits or more past the decimal point, for ex. "1.12" or "-1.12", niether will it match a number that starts with a decimal ".5"

Comment: Here is the complete regex that I ended up with for this `/^-?[0-9]?(\.[0-9]+)?$+/`.  I made the first number optional, making it so that it can start with a '.' and made the 2nd extend out infinitely.  I verified that both 1.12, -1.12, and .5 were all valid matches.

Comment: ok cool the one I came up with is /-?\d*(\.\d+)?\^-?\d*(\.\d+)?/  is there any difference between the two?

Comment: I don't believe yours is valid, due to the carat in the middle of the expression.  A carat indicates "I want this expression to start with the following".  You could easily shorten mine to `/^-?(\d+)?(\.\d+)?$+/` though.

Answer (score 2):

You need to execute this script from the command line, not a text editor, as you will be prompt to enter a number.

This is the ultra compact version

```
def validate(n)
  if (Float(n) != nil rescue return :invalid)
    return :zero if n.to_f == 0
    return :valid
  end
end
print "Please enter a number: "
puts "#{num = gets.strip} is #{validate(num)}"
```

Output:

```
Please enter a number: 00
00 is zero
```

Here is a longer version that problably you can extend it to tweak it to your needs.

```
class String
  def numeric?
    Float(self) != nil rescue false
  end
end

def validate(n)
  if n.numeric?
    return :zero if n.to_f == 0
    return :valid
  else
    return :invalid
  end
end

print "Please enter a number: "
puts "#{num = gets.strip} is #{validate(num)}"
```

And here is a test for all the possible cases

```
test_cases = [
  "33", #int pos
  "+33", #int pos
  "-33", #int neg
  "1.22", #float pos
  "-1.22", #float neg
  "10e5", #scientific notation
  "X", #STRING not numeric
  "", #empty string
  "0", #zero
  "+0", #zero
  "-0", #zero
  "0.00000", #zero
  "+0.00000", #zero
  "-0.00000", #zero
  "-999999999999999999999995444444444444444444444444444444444444434567890.99", #big num
  "-1.2.3", #version number
  "  9  ", #trailing spaces
]

puts "\n** Test cases **"
test_cases.each do |n|
  puts "#{n} is #{validate(n)}"
end
```

Which outputs:

```
Please enter a number: 12.34
12.34 is valid

** Test cases ** 33 is valid
+33 is valid
-33 is valid
1.22 is valid
-1.22 is valid
10e5 is valid
X is invalid
 is invalid
0 is zero
+0 is zero
-0 is zero
0.00000 is zero
+0.00000 is zero
-0.00000 is zero
-999999999999999999999995444444444444444444444444444444444444434567890.99 is valid
-1.2.3 is invalid
   9   is valid
```

Source for the idea of checking if its numeric:

- [How can I see if the string is numeric?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9469587/how-can-i-see-if-the-string-is-numeric)
- http://mentalized.net/journal/2011/04/14/ruby_how_to_check_if_a_string_is_numeric/